# Changing the text of an Options Button on Excel for Mac 365

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have made a workbook on Excel for Windows and I am now trying to get it to work on Excel for Mac.  (I have Office 365, so I have the most current versions of Excel on both computers.)  For the most part it works fine, but there are a few things that aren't working.  One bit that is really confusing me is changing the text of some Option Buttons that I have on a few different sheets.  (Based on some input, the text of the Option Buttons needs to change.)

In Excel for Windows, here's how I change the text:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("OptionButton1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "New Text"
```

The above works whether or not Sheet1 is the ActiveSheet, and whether or not OptionButton1 is in a column that is currently hidden.

That line of code does not work on Mac.  For it to work, I have to split it up, and introduce a Select command.  I also have to Activate the sheet.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

.Activate
.Shapes.Range(Array("OptionButton1")).Select
Selection.Characters.Text = "New Text"

End With
```

It's annoying that after the code runs, one Option Button is selected on each page.

Another annoying thing -- I have to make sure the column that the Option Button is in is not hidden.  I assume this is because I am being forced to select the Option Button itself, and it can’t do that if it’s in a hidden column?

I would love to NOT have to select the Option Button at all, but I can't figure out any other code to change the text.  To be honest, the only reason I was able to come up with *this* code is because I recorded a macro of myself actually doing it.

If anyone knows about Excel for Mac and could help, please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would add ActiveSheet to the code to prevent all objects named *Option Button 1* from being selected at the same time

> ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Option Button 1")).Select

Hiding columns does not affect option buttons' visible property on Mac or Windows. Option buttons have their own hidden/visible property.

Using this syntax works on both Mac and Windows, so why not go with it intstead of the older way?

Comment: Thanks, Jim!  I will give this a go!

Comment: And yes, to your point about the hidden/visible property, turns out I was mistaken.  The Option Button itself was set to hidden, so I had to change it to visible before changing the text.